# Share bluetooth device between different Windows OS on same machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, bluetooth

Is there a way to share device between different windows os'es on the same machine?

What I mean is:

1. I've got 2 system partitions

   - Windows 7
   - Windows 8
2. I want to share Wireless Entertainment Desktop 7000 set(mouse + keyboard) connected via Bluetooth (Microsoft Transceiver 3 from set) without pairing them every time I boot to another system.

How to do that?

Comment: You can check if the device can be set to auto-pair somehow, but otherwise sharing isn't possible the way you envisage it.

Comment: My idea was to pair it on both systems and then change pin in one of them. I do not know if it is possible and how to do it and that is why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered a similar post on :
[Finding Bluetooth link key in Windows 7, to double pair a device on dualboot computer](https://superuser.com/questions/229930/finding-bluetooth-link-key-in-windows-7-to-double-pair-a-device-on-dualboot-com).

That post was for a similar problem when pairing multi-booted Windows 7 and Ubuntu,
and the question was where does Windows 7 store its passkey,
which is the 128-bit key that the devices exchange during pairing and use thereafter to encrypt all their Bluetooth traffic.

My answer at that time was to look into the registry key at :
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys`.

This key is protected and one has to change its owner to Administrators to access or even see its sub-keys.

In theory, if you pair the device with both Windows installations and then
transport this registry key from the last-paired to the other,
then both installations will be
identical from the point of view of the bluetooth devices.

However, I do know that in Windows 8 many changes were done to the bluetooth protocol,
so this is not guaranteed to work,
but it would be interesting to see if this technique is still useful.

I suggest taking precautions before modifying the registry,
at least to create a system restore point.